# Quickly package/submitubuntu fails because of debhelper dependency

Tags: application-development, quickly

When running the submitubuntu or package command, I get this fatal error:

```
quickly.templatetools.CantUpdateFile: Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8), was not found in the file myproject/debian/control.
ERROR: submitubuntu command failed
```

The debhelper dependency in control is set by quickly itself, if I change it, it is changed back before packaging.

Comment: dpkg -s quickly tells me that the quickly version is `12.04-0ubuntu3` and quickly-ubuntu-template `12.04-0ubuntu4`

Comment: Hmm it might be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1022514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by upgrading, it was indeed this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1022514